# Omit namespace prefix only in object name jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, rss

I am creating an rss feed with jaxb, trying to follow google's rss 2.0 specification to make a product feed.

I have created my root object and set

```
     @XmlElement(name = "id", namespace="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
```

and created my own prefix mapper to generate prefixes (i know I could use package-info but didn't want the namespace being assigned to all my child elements)

```
     marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
        @Override
       public String getPreferredPrefix(String uri, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
           return uri.equals("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0") ? "g" : "";
       }
       });
```

However, my resulting root element xml is this:

```
<g:rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
```

when my desired result is this:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" >
```

How do I selectively omit the prefix from my name? the element name rss isn't part of google's namespace as far as I can tell

Comment: Hi, could you provide the full code of your root object ? Especially the part @XmlRootElement . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using my own xmlstreamwriter and just writing the root node manually and writing the rest of my objects as xml fragments:

```
    marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
        @Override
       public String getPreferredPrefix(String uri, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
           return uri.equals("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0") ? "g" : "";
       }
    });
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE); 



FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(fileWriter);
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeStartElement("rss");
        writer.writeAttribute("version", "2.0");
        writer.writeNamespace("g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");

        for (MyObject o : objects) 
        {
        marshaller.marshal(o, writer);
        writer.writeCharacters("\n");
        }            
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeEndDocument();
        writer.close();
```